# The Script is not cycling through images

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

So basically there is supposed to be a traffic light and it is supposed go through each image using CSS slide show however it is not working

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Picture1 = new Image()
Picture1.src = "Traffic_Red.png"
var Picture2 = new Image()
Picture2.src = "Traffic_Amber.png"
var Picture3 = new Image()
Picture3.src = "Traffic_Green.png"
var Picture4 = new Image()
Picture4.src = "Traffic_Amber.png"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="Traffic_Red.png" width="500" height="300" name="slide" /></p>




<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<4)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",3000);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: `setTimeout("slideit()",3000);` should be `setTimeout(slideit,3000);`

Comment: This appears to be almost identical to the previous question posted by Alon Eitan. Is this from (or for) a course?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> eval("image"+step+".src");
> ```

So you are trying to access `image1.src`

> ```
> var Picture1 = new Image()
> ```

… but you called it `Picture1` not `image1`.

You just need to get your variable names right.

---

That said, using `eval` to create variable variables is awful. Just use an array.

The `name` attribute for images has been deprecated in favour of `id`.

`setTimeout` is better passed a function than a string to be evaled.

```
<p><img src="Traffic_Red.png" width="500" height="300" id="slide" /></p>

<script>
    var pictures = [new Image(), new Image(), new Image(), new Image()];
    pictures[0].src = "Traffic_Red.png";
    pictures[1].src = "Traffic_Amber.png";
    pictures[2].src = "Traffic_Green.png";
    pictures[3].src = "Traffic_Amber.png";


    var step=0;
    function slideit() {
        document.getElementById('slide").src =  pictures[step].src;
        step++;
        if (step >= 4) {
            step = 0;
        }
        setTimeout("slideit", 3000);
    }

    slideit();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rename Variable name from Picture1,Picture2,Picture3 .... to image1,image2,image3 likewise Ex;

Replace :

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var Picture1 = new Image()
  Picture1.src = "Traffic_Red.png"
  var Picture2 = new Image()
  Picture2.src = "Traffic_Amber.png"
  var Picture3 = new Image()
  Picture3.src = "Traffic_Green.png"
  var Picture4 = new Image()
  Picture4.src = "Traffic_Amber.png"
</script>
</head>
```

With :

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var image1 = new Image()
        image1.src = "Traffic_Red.png"
        var image2 = new Image()
        image2.src = "Traffic_Amber.png"
        var image3 = new Image()
        image3.src = "Traffic_Green.png"
        var image4 = new Image()
        image4.src = "Traffic_Amber.png"
    </script>
</head>
```

and your script would like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            step++;
            if (step > 4) {
                step = 1;
            }
            setTimeout("slideit()",3000);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
```